# X11/Xlib.h file not found

Tags: macos, terminal, xcode, x11

I am trying to install [Savi-program for monitoring satellites](http://personal.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Personal/L.Wood/software/SaVi/building-under-Mac-OS-X/) found [here](http://savi.sourceforge.net/download/) via Terminal. I am developer so I have XCode installed. `which gcc` returns `/usr/bin/gcc`. Command `make ARCH=macosx` once in the directory is the code to execute. However, I am getting an error, saying `'X11/Xlib.h'`. Where do I get 'X11/Xlib.h' so that the program installs successfully?

This is the full error:

```
Mains-MBP:savi1.4.9 mainuser$ make ARCH=macosx
making all in manual...
making all in manual/images...
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
making all in bin...
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
making all in maps...
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
making all in oogl...
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
making all in data...
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
making all in tcl...
tclsh mkindex.tcl
making all in src...
making all in src/include...
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
gcc -O2 -DNO_ZLIB -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -ansi -I./include -I/opt/X11/include   -c -o main.o main.c
In file included from main.c:38:
In file included from ./include/tcl_utils.h:40:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/tk.h:78:11: fatal error: 
      'X11/Xlib.h' file not found
#       include <X11/Xlib.h>
                ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [main.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Did you have installed XQuartz?

Comment: The missing source file is needed for compiling programs using the X11 graphics system common for Linux systems (which MacOS don't support natively).  You do not have the needed dependencies installed on your system.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The instructions you [quote](http://personal.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Personal/L.Wood/software/SaVi/building-under-Mac-OS-X/) tell you exactly what the issue is

> When you type make you will be prompted to install Xcode. You can also install Xcode by typing the terminal command xcode-select --install
>
> If your compilation fails with an Xlib not found error, install XQuartz to get X11 headers under /opt/X11, and then type:

```
CPPFLAGS=-I/opt/X11/include
make ARCH=macosx
```

Comment: This worked for me on a similar problem with a different program